# Check MySql credentials before creating tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, wamp

I am creating an install php script that creates some tables in a database and creates a config file. Everything works but I don't know how to check if their host, username and password are correct. I currently check if the database is there or not.. any help would be appreciated. This is on a WAMP server using PHP 5.4.12. The variables come from a basic form.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['dbdatabase'] = $_POST['dbdatabase'];
$_SESSION['dbhost'] = $_POST['dbhost'];
$_SESSION['dbusername'] = $_POST['dbusername'];
$_SESSION['dbpassword'] = $_POST['dbpassword'];

$conn=mysqli_connect($_SESSION['dbhost'],$_SESSION['dbusername'],$_SESSION['dbpassword']);


if(!mysqli_select_db($conn, $_SESSION['dbdatabase']))
   {
   die ('Database does not exists. Please create a database before installing Pazzilla BackOffice.');
       }         
     else 
     {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [mysqli_connect_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php).

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'invalid_user', 'password');

if (!$link) {
    die('Invalid database credentials. Mysql said: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: That kills the script when the credentials are wrong so that works.. I guess I was looking for a way to send the user back if they got the host wrong or the username  etc...

Comment: You can always use a [`header()`](http://www.php.net/header) to redirect the user instead of `die();` @user114236

Comment: I don't generally use `die()`, but since you used it in your example, I just followed the same format. You could always set some sort of error variable and then echo it back to the user in a more friendly way.